# How to do interpolation on URL in Golang

Tags: go

I have the follow URL and I want to change the value of `start` for each iteration. Is there a better way to do it?

```
    test := "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?start=%d&cx=001106611627702700888%3Aaonktv-oz_w&q=bells%20palsy%20mouth&exactTerms=palsy&fileType=png&imgColorType=color&imgType=face&searchType=image&key=AIzaSyAYqQ4IxUHnF7rfvzSvnczxQ-u93AbkC8k"

for v := 1; v < 100; v += 10 {
    val := fmt.Sprintf(test, v)
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

Output now:

`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?start=1&cx=001106611627702700888%!A(MISSING)aonktv-oz_w&q=bells%!p(MISSING)alsy%!m(MISSING)outh&exactTerms=palsy&fileType=png&imgColorType=color&imgType=face&searchType=image&key=AIzaSyAYqQ4IxUHnF7rfvzSvnczxQ-u93AbkC8k`

Expected Output should be:

`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?startindex=1&q=bells%20palsy%20mouth
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?startindex=11&q=bells%20palsy%20mouth`

....etc.

Why `Sprintf` gives me `(MISSING)` and a couple of random characters?

Comment: Try `%d` in `test` instead of `%v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` characters that are not part of a format verb should be escaped as `%%`:

```
test := "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?start=%d&cx=001106611627702700888%%3Aaonktv-oz_w&q=bells%%20palsy%%20mouth&exactTerms=palsy&fileType=png&imgColorType=color&imgType=face&searchType=image&key=AIzaSyAYqQ4IxUHnF7rfvzSvnczxQ-u93AbkC8k"
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/E8UV48dg8W)

If the `%` are not escaped, then fmt expects to find a corresponding argument and complains with the output `(MISSING)` when the argument is not found.

Comment: Any idea why `%v` doesn't work? On https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ `%v` should result in the value in default format